# Determinant, and matrix identity for matrices of order N

Tags: python, tkinter, matrix

I need to make a program to show the determinant, and identity matrix for square matrices of any size.I've already done the part that solves the determinant and the identity matrix, I just need to create an interface for the user to type the size of the matrix and insert the elements. Then in the interface show the identity matrix and the value of the determinant.

How can I do this?

The code below is in Portuguese:

```
import numpy as np

from numpy import linalg

import requests

from tkinter import *

ordem = int(input('Insira a ordem da matriz : '))


matriz = np.zeros((ordem,ordem))

for l in range(0, ordem):
    for c in range(0, ordem):   
        matriz[l][c] = int(input(f'Digite um valor para [{l+1}, {c+1}] : '))


det = round(np.linalg.det(matriz))

print('Determinante da matriz {}x{} é = {}'.format(ordem, ordem, int(det)))

if det == 0:

    print('Não é possível diagonalizar essa matriz.')

else :

    matrizi = (np.eye(ordem))

    print(matrizi)
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, instead create a [mre] and post the code directly into your question and try to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it well. You should [edit] it before it gets closed.

Comment: @Thingamabobs Now it's right?

Comment: Its closer to meet the community guidelines of [ask]. But your question isn't clear, cause you do not have a GUI part in your code. Did you forgot to include code in your snippet? What do you actual need help with?

Comment: @Thingamabobs 
I didn't put the GUI because I don't know how to do it. I want help to make a GUI where I enter the size of the square matrix called "order" and boxes="Entrys" appear for me to place the elements of the matrix, with these elements I calculate the determinant

Comment: [so] is not a code writing service. You should take a look on one of the tkinter tutorials, there are countless on the web. In addition there are examples to use for loops for widgets including this site.

Comment: @Thingamabobs I posted another question, I searched and I didn't find tutorials in my language that teach how to mess with tkinter in the matrix part, even more NxN matrices